# LWJGL texture rendering/indexing

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, textures, lwjgl

I am currently having issues with trying to render two textures onto two totally separate objects through a single vertex, and fragment shader. The issue seems to lie in trying to index, and bind the two textures onto their own objects.  In trying to index and bind the textures, the smaller index will always appear onto both objects.

Can someone help me, or at least push me into the right direction?

here is my code for the main class, the renderer, and the fragment shader.
(feel free to request more code)

main:

```
import Engine.IO.Image;
import Engine.IO.Input;
import Engine.IO.Window;
import Engine.graphics.*;
import Engine.maths.Vector2f;
import Engine.maths.Vector3f;
import Engine.objects.Camera;
import Engine.objects.GameObject;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL13;

public class Main implements Runnable {
    public Thread game;
    public  Window window;
    public Renderer renderer;
    public Shader shader;
    public  final int WIDTH = 1280, HEIGHT = 720;
    private String[] textureImageNames = {"nice_dude.jpg", "color.jpg", "pepe.jpg"};

    public GameObject thing1 = new GameObject(new Vector3f(-1, 0, 0), new Vector3f(0, 0, 0), new Vector3f(1, 1, 1), new Mesh(new Vertex[]{
            new Vertex(new Vector3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f), new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), new Vector2f(0.0f,0.0f)),
            new Vertex(new Vector3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f), new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), new Vector2f(1.0f,0.0f)),
            new Vertex(new Vector3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f), new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), new Vector2f(1.0f,1.0f)),
            new Vertex(new Vector3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f), new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), new Vector2f(0.0f,1.0f))
    }, new int[]{
            0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2
    }), new Material(textureImageNames[0]));

    public GameObject thing2 = new GameObject(new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), new Vector3f(0, 0, 0), new Vector3f(1, 1, 1), new Mesh(new Vertex[]{
            new Vertex(new Vector3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f), new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), new Vector2f(0.0f,0.0f)),
            new Vertex(new Vector3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f), new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), new Vector2f(1.0f,0.0f)),
            new Vertex(new Vector3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f), new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), new Vector2f(1.0f,1.0f)),
            new Vertex(new Vector3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f), new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), new Vector2f(0.0f,1.0f))
    }, new int[]{
            0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2
    }), new Material(textureImageNames[2]));

    public Camera camera = new Camera(new Vector3f(0, 0, 1), new Vector3f(0, 0,0));

    public void start(){
        game = new Thread(this,"game");
        game.start();
    }

    public void init(){
        System.out.println("Initializing Game!");
        window = new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Game");
        shader = new Shader("/shaders/mainVertex.glsl", "/shaders/mainFragment.glsl");
        window.setBackgroundColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
        window.create();
        thing1.getMesh().create();
        thing2.getMesh().create();
        thing1.getMaterial().create(new Image());
        thing2.getMaterial().create(new Image());
        shader.create();
        renderer = new Renderer(window, shader);
        renderer.renderMesh();
        renderer.enableShaderProgram();
        renderer.bindVAO(thing1);
        renderer.bindVAO(thing2);
        renderer.setUniformIndex(thing1,"tex", GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        renderer.setUniformIndex(thing2,"tex2", GL13.GL_TEXTURE1);
    }

    public void run(){
        init();
        while(!window.shouldClose() && !Input.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE)){
            update();
            render();
            if(Input.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_F11)){window.setFullscreen(!window.isFullscreen());}
        }
        close();
    }

    private void update(){
        //System.out.println("updating Game!");
        window.update();
        camera.update();
    }

    private void render(){
        renderer.updateRenderer(thing1);
        renderer.updateRenderer(thing2);
        renderer.renderCamera(camera);
        window.swapBuffers();
    }

    private void close(){
        window.destroy();
        thing1.getMesh().destroy();
        thing1.destroyMaterial();
        thing2.getMesh().destroy();
        thing2.destroyMaterial();
        shader.destroy();
        renderer.destroyRenderer();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main().start();
    }
}
```

render class:

```
package Engine.graphics;

import Engine.IO.Window;
import Engine.maths.Matrix4f;
import Engine.objects.Camera;
import Engine.objects.GameObject;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

public class Renderer {
    private Shader shader;
    private Window window;

    public Renderer(Window window, Shader shader){
        this.shader = shader;
        this.window = window;
    }

    public void renderMesh() {
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    }

    public void enableShaderProgram(){
        shader.bind();
    }

    public void bindVAO(GameObject object){
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(object.getMesh().getVAO());
    }

    public void setUniformIndex(GameObject object, String textureName, int index){
        GL13.glActiveTexture(index);
        shader.setUniform(textureName, index);
        GL13.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, object.getMaterial().getTextureID());
    }

    public void updateRenderer(GameObject object){
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, object.getMesh().getIndices().length, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        shader.setUniform("model", Matrix4f.transform(object.getPosition(), object.getRotation(), object.getScale()));
        shader.setUniform("projection", window.getProjectionMatrix());
    }

    public void renderCamera(Camera camera){
        shader.setUniform("view", Matrix4f.view(camera.getPosition(), camera.getRotation()));
    }

    public void destroyRenderer(){
        shader.unBind();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 460 core

in vec3 passColor;
in vec2 passTextureCoord;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D tex2;

void main(){
    outColor = texture(tex, passTextureCoord);
    outColor = texture(tex2, passTextureCoord);
}
```

Comment: The most important part is missing in your code. Where you specify the vertex attributes, especially where do you specify the element buffer.

Comment: @Rabbid76 That information is located in my mesh class. This is the function in which does the vertex attribute works:                                                                private int storeData(FloatBuffer buffer, int index, int size){
        int bufferID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(index, size, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        return bufferID;
    }

Comment: @Rabbid Also the element buffer is specified in the mesh class, in which, I give it this information: IntBuffer indicesBuffer = MemoryUtil.memAllocInt(indices.length);
        indicesBuffer.put(indices).flip();                                                                                                                                     ibo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);

Comment: The `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is state in the Vertex Array Object. Is the VAO bound (`glBindVertexArray`) before the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is bound (`GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...)`)?

Comment: @Rabbid76 why would I bind the VAO before the EBO when the EBO is part of the VAO?

Comment: When a buffer is bound to the target `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, then this buffer is associated to the vertex array object which is currently bound. First bind the VAO, then state the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` in the VAO. See [Index buffers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers)

Comment: @Rabbid76 okay, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value which has to be set to the texture sampler uniform is the index of the texture unit rather then the texture unit constant (e.g.: 0 for `GL13.GL_TEXTURE0` and 1 for `GL13.GL_TEXTURE1`):

```py
public void setUniformIndex(GameObject object, String textureName, int unit, int index){
    shader.setUniform(textureName, index);
    GL13.glActiveTexture(unit);
    GL13.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, object.getMaterial().getTextureID());
}
```

OpenGL is a state engine. Binding a VAO and or a texture object changes a global state. It is not possible to bind 2 objects at once. Only the last object which was bound is stated. You have to bind the Vertex Array Object and the texture object before the draw call:

```py
private void render(){
        
    renderer.bindVAO(thing1);
    renderer.setUniformIndex(thing1,"tex", GL13.GL_TEXTURE0, 0);
    renderer.updateRenderer(thing1);
    
    renderer.bindVAO(thing2);
    renderer.setUniformIndex(thing2,"tex2", GL13.GL_TEXTURE1, 1);
    renderer.updateRenderer(thing2);
    
    renderer.renderCamera(camera);
    window.swapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the information you provided was very useful.